# No REPL prompt when running from `make`

Tags: makefile, clojure, gnu-make, fish

When running a Clojure or ClojureScript REPL from `make`, no prompt is rendered.

Makefile:

```
clojure:
    clojure
```

Then when doing `make clojure` I do not get the prompt that I would get when running just `clojure`.

(This is ofcourse a minimal example Makefile.)

Comment: It's almost always a bad idea to invoke an interactive command from within a makefile.  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Convenience. `clojure --main cljs.main --compile source.core --repl` builds the source, starts up a browser to test it and keeps a REPL open. So it's not that I want to run just an interactive command, it just comes with the whole package.

Comment: I can not reproduce this with the given example on Debian. Could you share more information about how to reproduce this with the given example?

Comment: Well, it's not really reliable to do that.  For one thing, if you run `make -j` then only one of the parallel jobs will get stdin.  The rest will not.  Which one gets it and which one doesn't is essentially random.

Comment: Right, I didn't think of that, @MadScientist. Thanks!

Comment: @cfrick I'm using the fish shell. If I switch to Bash it works as it should, so thanks for clearing this up!

Comment: Ahh. Set the `SHELL` variable in your makefile then. (I'm surprised that `fish` exports that variable to the environment -- it's not a great idea since it has potential to change how other applications work, and if fish _didn't_ do that, make would have no way of knowing that fish was in use)

Comment: Perhaps use a Bash/Zsh alias (or function!) w/o the Makefile?  `alias cljr="clojure --main cljs.main --compile source.core --repl"`.  Or, just shove the entire command into a file `cljr.bash`

Comment: (Also, I agree with the "don't launch interactive things from makefiles" consensus wholeheartedly).

Comment: @AlanThompson, remember that the OP uses at least two different shells (bash and fish). An executable script is going to be more reliable than a shell alias or shell function, as it works the same way from any shell or when being directly exec'd with no shell at all. Line one, `#!/bin/sh`, line two, `exec clojure --main cljs.main --compile source.core --repl "$@"`, and there you are.

Comment: @AlanThompson, ...also, boo hiss re: putting filename extensions on shell scripts (see the essay [Commandname extensions considered harmful](https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/), as linked from the #bash IRC channel's factoid database at https://wooledge.org/~greybot/meta/.sh)

Comment: Enjoying the discussion guys! Anyone want to answer with a summary so I can accept it?

Comment: Also I'm using a Makefile as a single point of reference for how to use the project (mostly for myself in 6 months), but a README is starting to look good as well ;-)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy why not "launch interactive things from makefiles"? I often use it to shorten commands (e.g. `make psql` instead of the whole command to open container et cetera) and have experienced no problems.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to stand by most of the comments here saying that you **really shouldn't** include interactive commands in your `Makefile`.. however to answer your question you could do something like this:

Let's say you have the following alias in your project's `deps.edn` file:

```
{
  ...

  :repl {:extra-deps {nrepl/nrepl {:mvn/version "RELEASE"}
                      cider/cider-nrepl {:mvn/version "RELEASE"}}
    :main-opts ["-m" "nrepl.cmdline" "--interactive" "--middleware" "[\"cider.nrepl/cider-middleware\"]"]}

  ...
}
```

then you could simply add a target to your `Makefile` like this:

```
repl:
    clj -A:repl
```

and that would launch a repl on your command line along with the nrepl middleware so that you may still connect to it from your IDE.